# How to use intitializer list?

Tags: c++

**Edit: Cannot use vectors**

So right now I am practicing with classes, and headers. One of the things I need to do is create a constructor that can initialize a 2D array using the initializer list.

I have used this website to try and figure out how to do so: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

But it doesn't really help me at all.

So far I have the constructors prototype, along with the includes and a typedef for the intitializer list:

```
#include <initializer_list>
typedef initializer_list<initializer_list<double>> i_list;

Matrix::Matrix(const i_list & list)
{}
```

I need to  be able to do something like `x = {{1,2},{2,4}}` and this should enable me to create my Matrix --x--- without having to call my .at function.

Edit:

I tried executing the following code, but sadly it does result in errors.

```
Matrix::Matrix(const i_list & list)
{

  lst.size(list.size());
  for (auto const& row: list)
  {

        (lst.begin(row),lst.end(row));
  }
}
```

lst is defined in my header file as: I_list lst. I_list since it is a shorthand.

Comment: I think that typedef is a bad idea, as it obscures the fact that the argument is `std::initializer_list` and because `std::initializer_list` has reference semantics not value semantics, it is not a good idea to hide that you're using it. Also, you're missing `std::` on the types.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(const i_list& lst)
    {
        values.reserve(lst.size());
        for (auto const& row : lst)
        {
            values.emplace_back(std::begin(row), std::end(row));
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> values;
};
```

Instead of raw arrays, you can use `std::vector`. One of the available constructors for `std::vector` takes a `begin` and `end` iterator, which are available for `std::initializer_list`.

[Working demo](http://cpp.sh/6zfd)

```
int main()
{
    Matrix x = {{1,2},{2,4}};

    for (auto const& row : x.values)
    {
        for (double value : row)
        {
            std::cout << value << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output

```
1 2 
2 4
```

Comment: Another of the `vector<double>` constructors takes `initializer_list<double>` so you can just do `values.push_back(row);`

Comment: How could I go about this without using the vector class? Sadly, I am not allowed to do so. I noticed on the cpp reference that it seemed as though the list also has a beginning and ending?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to take a `std::initializer_list` by reference-to-const. It's going to be constructed in place anyway. And you don't actually need the body of your constructor, since you can use the `std::vector` iterator constructor.

I would propose simply:

```
Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<double> > lst)
: values{lst.begin(), lst.end()}
{ }
```

Comment: I see, but from where does values come from? Also, I cannot use vectors.

Comment: @SomeStudent Well what are the members of `Matrix` that you are trying to initialize? You don't specify in the question, so I assumed the same as CoryKramer that you had a `vector<vector<double>>`.

Comment: Well, per my understanding when we say Matrix X = {{1,2} , {2,1}} for example, it is suppose to call the constructor which is Matrix(const I_list & list)

Comment: @SomeStudent Well, it depends on what the other constructors of `Matrix` are, if `Matrix` is an aggregate, etc. But you didn't answer the question. What are the *members* of `Matrix` that you need to initialize? And put that in the question.

Comment: Not super sure what you mean by the members of Matrix. But if it is what I think I do, then my Matrix is represented by a double 2D array called myArray. It takes rows and cols as its parameters. So I do have another constructor called Matrix(uint row, uint col) which initializes a matrix to 0. This if I were to say Matrix d(2,2) it would create a 2x2 matrix all set to 0.